# Can't grab the max value of a pandas df due to dtype error --> TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df containing strings which I converted to floats as the `dytpe` check confirms:

```
date       object
open      float64
high      float64
low       float64
close     float64
volume    float64
```

```
# Transform strings to floats
df_new['close'] = df_new['close'].astype(float)
df_new['high'] = df_new['high'].astype(float)
df_new['low'] = df_new['low'].astype(float)
df_new['open'] = df_new['open'].astype(float)
df_new['volume'] = df_new['volume'].astype(float)
print(df_new.dtypes)

# Get max 
max_price = df_new.loc[df['open'].idxmax()]
```

Now when I try to grab the max value it throws a dtype error

> TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Why's that and how to further investigate / fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You are using `df` not `df_new` inside `.loc`. Could you try the following:

```py
max_price = df_new.loc[df_new['open'].idxmax()]
```

Or if you want to use `df` then try:

```py
max_price = df_new.loc[df['open'].astype(float).idxmax()]
```

Comment: awww...too early in the day -- thanks